# i want to get subsource_type value using console.log in php using api

Tags: php, forms, api, submit

Output code when i submit lead form, now i want to display response: sourcetype using console.log

{
 "code": 200,
  "message": "Successfully added.",
  "response": {
    "SourceType": "Digital SEM",
    "SubSourceType": "Organic",
    "VendorName": "",
    "Uid": "",
    "Phone": "919897990797",
    "LeadId": 2413493
  }
}

Comment: Do you get this return value by an ajax request? Please post your code

Comment: i am using api, when we submit form we get that values now i want to get response: SourceType details in console.log how i get/print it ?

Comment: it is ok or not:

console.log (data [response]);

Comment: It depends on what kind of "submit" do you use, you must post some code for more clarity.